# javascript getting the html element that fired the onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<a class="button-dashboard-save" href="#" onclick="return interface.saveChanges();">Save</a>
```

inside the interface.saveChanges() i want to get the element object that fired that function, I mean the whole a element.

Regards,

Comment: Pass `this` as function parameter or better don't use inline script but bind event using js/jq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you want to reference the anchor element `<a>` inside `interface.saveChanges`.  In this case you can directly pass the `this` keyword to the function.  The code should look like:

```html
<a class="button-dashboard-save" href="#" 
   onclick="return interface.saveChanges(this);">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` inside the inline onclick. It will pass the current clicked element in your case.

```
<a class="button-dashboard-save" href="#" onclick="return interface.saveChanges(this);">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a event handler function ( using jquery for simplicity ):

```
$(".button-dashboard-save").click ( function ( eve ) {
    return interface.saveChanges ( eve.target );
});
```

This provides `interface.saveChanges` with the triggering element as a parameter.

Your html slightly simplifies:

```
 <a class="button-dashboard-save" href="#">Save</a>
```